# sql Command has not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using sql developer and netbeans when ever i try to insert data into the table this error "sql Command has not properly ended".
This is what i tried.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        dbconnection db = new dbconnection();
        try {
            db.connect();
            db.stm = db.con.createStatement();
            int result = db.stm.executeUpdate(
                "insert into payment values'" + txt_paymentid.getText() + "','" + txt_reservation.getText() +"',
                " + "'"+txt_fname.getText()+"',
                '"+txt_lname.getText()+"'  ,'"+txt_roomid.getText()+"'  ,'"+txt_rate.getText()+"'  ," + "  '"+((JTextField)txt_datein.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()+"'  ,"
                + "'"
((JTextField
            )txt_dateout.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText() + "'," + "'" + txt_days.getText() + "','" + txt_payment.getText() + "','" + txt_balance.getText() + "'"
            ); 
            if (result > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data has been saved succesfully");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "no data has been saved");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Java code?

Comment: What do you see if you print your constructed SQL statement out to console? What happens if you try to run that generated statement? Can you see that it isn't valid (missing parentheses, for a start)? And why aren't you using a prepared statement and giving the various text strings as bind variables instead of trying to embed them?

Comment: There is no missing parantheses 
When i click the button this "sql command has not properly ended " show up  .
There are other insert statements that are working berfectly and they look like this but i was thinking that the table is the problem  i deleted the table from the database and recreated but the error remains the same all other insertions are working

Comment: @suldanka - you are missing parentheses around the contents of the values clause, as ScaryWombat already pointed out. You're constructing something like `insert into payment values'x','y','z'` (which throws ORA-00933) instead of `insert into payment values ('x','y','z')`. This is a basic syntax problem. Which would be easier for you to spot if you used prepared statements, but also pretty easy if you just printed out your constructed statement.

Answer (score 1):

For a start

The sql should be in the `()`

```
executeUpdate()("insert...
```

->

```
executeUpdate("insert...)
```

second it looks like the insert command itself it not valid

```
insert into table values (' ....
```

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: you missed my second point, the insert command is not valid (and it is a mess) - see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: You should be able to get the insert command working by copying and pasting it into a sql client